# Error 150 create table sql

Tags: mysql

Al crear la siguiente tabla me da error 150 : "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

```
    create table seproduce (
    año_s   INT   NOT NULL, 
    mes_s   varchar(30)   NOT NULL, 
    dia_s   INT   NOT NULL, 
    id_producto     INT  NOT NULL, 
    cantidad_1   INT  NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(año_s, mes_s, dia_s, id_producto),
    FOREIGN KEY(año_s)  REFERENCES fecha(año_s),
    FOREIGN KEY(mes_s)  REFERENCES fecha(mes_s),
    FOREIGN KEY(dia_s)  REFERENCES fecha(dia_s),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_producto) REFERENCES producto(id_producto)
);
```

Las tablas a las que se refiere son las siguientes

```
create table producto (
id_producto    INT  PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
nombre_p    varchar(30)        NOT NULL,
tamaño      INT  NOT NULL,
sabor  varchar(30)   NOT NULL
);

create table periodo (
año_sem    INT  PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
gasto_per    INT       NOT NULL,
sueldos_per      INT  NOT NULL
);

create table fecha (
año_s   INT   NOT NULL,
mes_s   varchar(30) NOT NULL,
dia_s   INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(año_s, mes_s, dia_s),
año_sem  INT    NOT NULL, 
FOREIGN KEY(año_sem)  REFERENCES periodo(año_sem)
);
```

Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si aquí tienes:

```
create table fecha (
año_s   INT   NOT NULL,
mes_s   varchar(30) NOT NULL,
dia_s   INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(año_s, mes_s, dia_s),
año_sem  INT    NOT NULL, 
FOREIGN KEY(año_sem)  REFERENCES periodo(año_sem)
);
```

Cometes un error de sintaxis en la tabla `fecha` , ya que creas la columna `año_sem` después de la CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY . En el tipo de sintaxis que estás usando debes especificar primero las columnas y luego lo demás.

Me refiero a estas líneas:

<s>`PRIMARY KEY(año_s, mes_s, dia_s),
    año_sem  INT    NOT NULL,`</s>

como `año_sem  INT    NOT NULL` aparece después de la CONSTRAINT de PRIMARY KEY el manejador chilla, pues debes crear primero todas las columnas y luego agregar las CONSTRAINTS de lugar.

Entonces debería ser:

```
create table fecha (
año_s   INT   NOT NULL,
mes_s   varchar(30) NOT NULL,
dia_s   INT NOT NULL,
año_sem  INT    NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY(año_s, mes_s, dia_s),
FOREIGN KEY(año_sem)  REFERENCES periodo(año_sem)
);
```

Otra cosa es si indicas la PRIMARY KEY al lado del nombre de la columna, pero eso no puedes hacerlo con la tabla `fecha` porque la misma posee una PK compuesta. Para más detalles al respecto puedes consultar: [MySQL Primary Key](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-primary-key/).

Por cierto, yo no usaría `ñ` para nombres de columnas. Puedes usar por ejemplo `annio`.

Y también, no sé si en la tabla `fecha` las columnas `año_sem` y `año_s` hacen referencia a lo mismo ¿?

### EDIT

En el caso de la tabla `seproduce` quieres usar la PK (compuesta) de la tabla `fecha` como FK en `seproduce`. Tendrías que hacerlo del siguiente modo:

```
 create table seproduce (
    año_s   INT   NOT NULL, 
    mes_s   varchar(30)   NOT NULL, 
    dia_s   INT   NOT NULL, 
    id_producto     INT  NOT NULL, 
    cantidad_1   INT  NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(año_s, mes_s, dia_s, id_producto),
    FOREIGN KEY(año_s,mes_s,dia_s)  REFERENCES fecha(año_s,mes_s,dia_s),
--  FOREIGN KEY(año_s)  REFERENCES fecha(año_s),
--  FOREIGN KEY(mes_s)  REFERENCES fecha(mes_s),
--  FOREIGN KEY(dia_s)  REFERENCES fecha(dia_s),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_producto) REFERENCES producto(id_producto)
 );
```

Comment: Mil gracias! pero una duda: ¿Por qué me da el error después y no al crear la tabla fecha?

Comment: @JavierRussellRichardsValenz No entiendo bien lo que preguntas en el comentario. Edité la respuesta, pues en realidad el error era que la columna `año_sem  INT    NOT NULL, ` se estaba creando después de la CONSTRAINT de PRIMARY KEY, si la pones antes, funcionará con `año_sem`, aunque no sé si es lo mismo que `año_s`.

Comment: Se refieren a cosas distintas. A todo esto, yo puedo crear mi tabla fecha sin problemas, el problema es en la tabla "seproduce" y esta no se refiere al campo que debería tener error en la tabla fecha (año_sem)

Comment: Aún sigue el problema, al parecer no era eso.

Comment: @JavierRussellRichardsValenz Revisa el **EDIT** de la respuesta. Lo he probado en fiddle y funciona. Para `seproduce`, tienes que agregar un solo  FK apuntando a fecha, con las tres columnas: `FOREIGN KEY(año_s,mes_s,dia_s)  REFERENCES fecha(año_s,mes_s,dia_s)...`

Comment: @JavierRussellRichardsValenz ¿ verificaste la solución planteada en el EDIT ?

Comment: Me funcionó, muchas gracias! disculpa por no responder, pensé que lo había hecho!